# Read-only file system error while uploading image/files in django site in Vercel hosting

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, vercel, django-deployment

I have deployed my django site in vercel(using free hosting plan). Now while I am trying to create a model object (**which has image/file field**) from admin panel, is not saving. Instead of this it is showing that
`OSError at /admin/portfolio/biodata/add/ [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/task/media'`
I think media folder is saved in `/var/task/media` this directory and this directory doesn't have any permission to write it.
Here is my models.py:

```
class Biodata(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/profile_pic')
    about_me = models.TextField()
    cv_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    ....
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, can anyone tell me that how can I override the permission or solve this issue so that I can upload images or files from admin panel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Vercel doesn't support file uploads on a serverless function during runtime. [Read this](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/314#discussioncomment-3609594) for more information and alternatives.